# How can I connect to SQLServer Container locally?

Tags: sql-server, docker, sql-server-2022

if I
`docker run -d --name sql-server2 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=Password" -p 1434:1433 mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server`

I don't get any errors, but I can't connect to SQLServer

I have tried:

1. `telnet [IP ADDRESS] [PORT` and it times out
2. i have verified that the PORT is open and not being used by my local SQL Server instance or any other service!
3. tried to connect via SSMS using both the IP address and Container Name
4. tried verified that SQL Server is running and configured to listen on port 1434

-- but this failed

a. `docker exec -it mydb /bin/bash`

b. tried selecting the details but this failed:

`/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P Password -Q "SELECT @@SERVERNAME, @@SERVICENAME, @@VERSION, @@SPID"`

which led to...

```
docker run -e "MSSQL_PID=Express" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Password" -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED=true" --name mydb -p 1434:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P Password -Q "CREATE LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD='Password'; ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER sa;"
```

c. the i looked at the logs `docker logs mydb`

```
docker logs mydb
SQL Server 2022 will run as non-root by default.
This container is running as user mssql.
To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

but the container is running and everything looks good!

Here is the container config `docker inspect`

```
[
    {
        "Id": "17642d4edec294a00b3be832140ffe3f5d4d8b343206238f5edb8ea7bca736cd",
        "Created": "2023-04-11T07:10:19.5252757Z",
        "Path": "/opt/mssql/bin/permissions_check.sh",
        "Args": [
            "/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 19452,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2023-04-11T07:10:20.008256Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:880c02b9631c5813e3e5d0ed8cb0aaca6db059311d41d199dd0409b7850410ef",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/17642d4edec294a00b3be832140ffe3f5d4d8b343206238f5edb8ea7bca736cd/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/17642d4edec294a00b3be832140ffe3f5d4d8b343206238f5edb8ea7bca736cd/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/17642d4edec294a00b3be832140ffe3f5d4d8b343206238f5edb8ea7bca736cd/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/17642d4edec294a00b3be832140ffe3f5d4d8b343206238f5edb8ea7bca736cd/17642d4edec294a00b3be832140ffe3f5d4d8b343206238f5edb8ea7bca736cd-json.log",
        "Name": "/mydb",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "1433/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "1434"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                49,
                125
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/68e3260d1b95dac0b023d84eea5c7ebfdb785b7534f2c6a4ff671cca5f379114-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5561ebee37fca08ca058b75bc37a48219d8d58efd4c96adabf45a4d123997938/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9b41bbea0461ab92801af054005716807e709bfde699f2b9ea53617564debcda/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5ff6d36410dd1a91db24921858d6218214c6244168d4f2d8759a9289af9c7a1e/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/68e3260d1b95dac0b023d84eea5c7ebfdb785b7534f2c6a4ff671cca5f379114/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/68e3260d1b95dac0b023d84eea5c7ebfdb785b7534f2c6a4ff671cca5f379114/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/68e3260d1b95dac0b023d84eea5c7ebfdb785b7534f2c6a4ff671cca5f379114/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "17642d4edec2",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "mssql",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "1433/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "ACCEPT_EULA=Y",
                "SA_PASSWORD=Str0ngPatable {{.ID}}\\t{{.Names}}\\t{{.Image}}w0rd",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "MSSQL_RPC_PORT=135",
                "CONFIG_EDGE_BUILD="
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr"
            ],
            "Image": "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/opt/mssql/bin/permissions_check.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.microsoft.product": "Microsoft SQL Server",
                "com.microsoft.version": "16.0.4015.1",
                "org.opencontainers.image.ref.name": "ubuntu",
                "org.opencontainers.image.version": "20.04",
                "vendor": "Microsoft"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "ceeee24cb170cf31af95b1dae783b2b0723ca9479bc25c0b9bd1a99cfe6f5bfe",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "1433/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "1434"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/ceeee24cb170",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "845b8cd09ea93424b8513448d5e40f0b8f54a547cbea33c9d21967bc8cc5c5f0",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "b863a6384ac30b2a71ed46777ceb755a19229ddcf6353c3ca2d808f988028948",
                    "EndpointID": "845b8cd09ea93424b8513448d5e40f0b8f54a547cbea33c9d21967bc8cc5c5f0",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

and here is the firewall rule:

`netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all`

```
Rule Name:                            Sql2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled:                              Yes
Direction:                            In
Profiles:                             Domain,Private,Public
Grouping:                             
LocalIP:                              Any
RemoteIP:                             Any
Protocol:                             TCP
LocalPort:                            1434
RemotePort:                           Any
Edge traversal:                       Yes
Action:                               Allow
```

Comment: *tried verified that SQL Server is running and configured to listen on port 1434* what exactly do you mean by that? Did you reconfigure the sql server instance in your container so that it listens to port 1434? Or do you just mean your portmapping? And I'm also not quite sure what you mean with your *and this led to*  line? Are you manually trying to create the user `sa`?

Comment: `-p 1434:1433` are you sure about this? You're trying to expose port 1433 instead of the port SQL Server runs on, 1434

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the default instance of SQL Server (i.e.: the MSSQLSERVER instance) listens on tcp/1433. It's the Dedicated Admin Connection that listens on tcp/1434 and then only on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: You need to differentiate between the Docker container running and the mssql service within it. The container starts immediately and launches the mssql service, but the mssql service has to validate all of the system database files and user database files (and rollback any incomplete transactions) before it actually accepts connections on the listening port - which is why sqlcmd cannot connect immediately. It can take tens of seconds before the server is listening and ready to accept connections, depending on the size of the files involved and available resources.

Comment: You're right. The `-p` is messing up the ports anyway

Comment: Question... the `sa` account already exists within the instance. What do you expect to happen when sqlcmd connects with `sa` credentials and then tries to create the `sa` account again?

Comment: If you run `netstat /ant | find "1434"` on the Docker host what addresses is it actually listening on? If it's only listening on `127.0.0.1` then you will only be able to connect from the Docker host itself with `127.0.0.1,1434` using SSMS and other SQL tools.

Comment: Also, wrt `Password`, when you watch the container log as it starts do you see an error message similar to, _ERROR: Unable to set system administrator password: Password validation failed. The password does not meet SQL Server password policy requirements because it is not complex enough. The password must be at least 8 characters long and contain characters from three of the following four sets: Uppercase letters, Lowercase letters, Base 10 digits, and Symbols._

Comment: I have the exact same issue albeit with SQLServer 2019 images .  I can happily run a bash session but `docker inspect <containerId>`  shows a lot of info but no ip address . Again I am not getting anywhere with `docker inspect \
  -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}} <containerId>`

Comment: thanks guys for all the comments, one of my devs fixed it; i'll share the solution...